# CORS Issue with API running on Web2Py

Tags: cors, web2py

I've searching a lot and although I found similar issues, it seems that I haven't found my answer yet and maybe you can help me.

I have the following API on my Web2Py framework and I am accessing it with a AngularJS front-end app and I am having CORS issues (I already tried * in the orign or my specific IP and port but no good results). Nevertheless, it does work with IE but not with Chrome or Mozilla.

```
@request.restful()
def api():
    def GET():
        key = main() #generate random XML and returns the key
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = '*'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = 86400
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = '*'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
        response.view = 'generic.xml'
        value = cb.get(key).value #get value stored into couchbase
        return value
    return dict(GET=GET)
```

More details about the error from the front-end app:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my_IP:8000/my_app/default/api/.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://my_IP:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 405.

From my front-end app I am sure I have the right function for calling the API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your response headers need to go outside of the GET() function.

```
@request.restful()
def api():
    response.view = 'generic.json'
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = 86400
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'

    def GET(tablename, id):
        if not tablename == 'person':
            raise HTTP(400)
        return dict(person = db.person(id))

    def POST(tablename, **fields):
        if not tablename == 'person':
            raise HTTP(400)
        return db.person.validate_and_insert(**fields)

    return locals()
```

http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services?search=restful#Low-level-API-and-other-recipes

Comment: How to handle also the authentication trough session?

Comment: Setting 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' to 'true' will not work if 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is set to '*'.

Answer (score -1):

Apply this method and see magic:

```
def cors_origin():
    origin = request.env.http_origin
    headers = {}
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin

    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true';
    response.headers.update(headers)

    if request.env.request_method == 'OPTIONS':
        headers['Content-Type'] = None
        raise HTTP(200, '', **headers)


def cors_allow(action):

    def f(*args, **kwargs):
        cors_origin()
        return action(*args, **kwargs)

    f.__doc__ = action.__doc__
    f.__name__ = action.__name__
    f.__dict__.update(action.__dict__)

    return f



@cors_allow
@request.restful()
def api():
    def GET():
       return dict(msg="success")  
    return locals()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The combination of `headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin` and `headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'` is very insecure!