# Angular rest web2py

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, rest, web2py

i can't conect my server web2py restful with angular Ajax,
but if i set the url  in my browser it's fine it work , but i cant in  angular ajax =(

**Link of  Angular**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

**Mi code in my server web2py  (Controller)**

```
@request.restful()
def api(): 
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
    response["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = "1000"
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"
    response.view = 'generic.json'
    def GET():
            print "asdasds"
            return dict(content="JAJAJAJAJA")

    return dict(GET=GET)
```

and mi AJax in angular 
**url= Address:port/nameProject/controller/action**

```
  app.controller('controlVentas',  function( $http) {
  var app = this; 
  app.CargarLlave=function(){ 
       var respuesta=$http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/Hoteles/ControlMSR/api");
       respuesta.success(function(data){ 
                   alert( "OK"); 
              });
       respuesta.error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                  alert( "NOOOOO"); 
           });  
  } 
});
```

**error of angular**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/Hoteles/ControlMSR/api. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:57734' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: it's `$http.get`, not `$http.GET`.  yes, case does matter here, and this is the angular `get()` function, not the `GET` method on the server that is being called.  also, you aren't providing `$http` in your controller injections.  try `app.controller('controlVentas', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'get' of undefined with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24478293/cannot-read-property-get-of-undefined-with-angular)

Comment: now evolution mi problem, one sec to  update

Comment: in mi controller is called,method and it work, is actived but dont respond nothing. O.o

Comment: you need to have CORS.  `127.0.0.1:8000` and `127.0.0.1:57734` **are not the same site**.  try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34621368/cors-issue-with-api-running-on-web2py, for example.

Comment: you are missing `.headers` in your response calls.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to set response headers is via `response.headers`, not directly on the `response` object. For example:

```
response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is my final Code,  thanks all =)**

**Code in mi  Web2Py**

```
@request.restful()
def api():
    response.view = 'generic.json'
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = 86400
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'

    def GET():
         names = ['1dddedede', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
         return dict(person=names)

    return locals()
```

**Code  in Angular**

```
app.controller('controlVentas',  function( $http) {
  var app = this; 
  app.CargarLlave=function(){ 
       var respuesta=$http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/Hoteles/ControlMSR/api");
       respuesta.success(function(data){ 
                   alert( "OK"); 
              });
       respuesta.error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                  alert( "NOOOOO"); 
           });  
  } 
});
```